# Compiler Error for classes in hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have the following code

```
class interfaceBase // abstract class
{
public:
    virtual void vf1() = 0;
};

class tempBase : public interfaceBase  // manages a resource
{
    tempBase(int a) { var = new int[a]; }
    ~tempBase(){ free(var); }
private:
    int* var;
};

class derived : public tempBase // class I intend to instantiate.
{
public:
    derived(int rhs){ tempBase(var); } // ERROR - Pasted below
    void vf1() override final {}
};

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    derived d(a);
}
```

I have a resource that needs to be managed, I created a seperate class called `tempBase` whose job is to manage that resource. However, this leaves me with a problem - I cannot construct objects of type `derived`, because there seems no means to call the constructor to `tempBase`

I get the error saying

```
error C2512: 'tempBase' : no appropriate default constructor available
error C2259: 'tempBase' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

How can I change my code such that I might still have all the resource management handled by `tempBase`, and have `derived` instantiable also.

Comment: Side note: you should use virtual inheritance, when deriving form interfaces. Also have a virtual destructor in the interface (base class)

Comment: @DieterLücking Can you please explain why use virtual inheritence?This seems to do the job.

Comment: That should not solve your problem - use a class initializer list.

Comment: @DieterLücking I mean Christophe's answer works without using virtual inheritence. It compiles.

Comment: The virtual inheritance of interfaces avoids duplication of the same interface if a  you have multiple base classes (interfaces) or combine interfaces

Comment: @DieterLücking should `class derived : public tempBase` also be made `virtual public`, or only `class tempBase : public interfaceBase`?

Comment: To end it here: Just First : virtual public Interface (virtual public Interface for each interface involved) - no need for a Second : virtual public First.

Comment: Offtopic, but calling free on data allocated using new results in UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ave to put this in the initializer list:

```
derived(int rhs) : tempBase(var) { } // No erroranymore - see below
```

Some additional explanation about the errors in your original code:

- As there was no initializer for `tempBase`, the compiler tried to generate a  default constructor, so that all member variables are constructed before executing the constructor body.
- You `tempBase(var)` in the body would create an additional temporary anonymous object of class `tempBase`, but such direct instantiation of a pure virtual class is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

When constructing the base part of a derived object you need to use

```
derived(vars) : base(vars) { constructor code here }
```